# SSIS Error "A buffer failed while allocating 104851104 bytes."

Tags: c#, ssis, out-of-memory, buffer, dataflow

Following are the errors reported in Data-Flow Tasks:

1. A buffer failed while allocating 104851104 bytes.
2. The system reports 69 percent memory load. There are 34358837248 bytes of physical memory with 10318077952 bytes free. There are 4294836224 bytes of virtual memory with 376406016 bytes free. The paging file has 38653804544 bytes with 14333120512 bytes free.
3. The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0x8007000E.

I have tried setting DefaultBufferMaxRows to 10000 and DefaultBufferSize:10MB
Increased the RAM to 64GB from 32GB

Dataflow Task

Comment: Is your project set for 64 bit mode?  I had similar issues with a project set to x86 mode and use 64 bit mode solved issue.

Comment: It is set for 32 bit mode

Comment: Did you try 64 bit mode?